# Error in making request to cURL

Tags: php, curl

I want to send data to this curl

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'where={"name":{"$regex":"^Big Daddy"}}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_User
```

So far I am successful in making curl but I cant integrate the `--data-urlencode` part. Can anyone verify my mistake? Thanks.

```
$str = $_POST['STR'];
$query = 'where={"name":{"$regex":"'.$str.'"}}';
$query = [
    "where" => '"name":{"$regex":"$str"}'
];
$url = "http://ec2-34-204-170-24.compute-1.amazonaws.com/parse/classes/_User";
$encoded_url = urlencode($url);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($query));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = [
    'X-Parse-Application-Id: YOLO',
    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key: 4314b22c8b68ed18cf42d'
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: {"code":200,"error":"bad or missing username"}

Comment: You realise you are using two different URLs right?
`https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_User` in the CLI and `http://ec2-34-204-170-24.compute-1.amazonaws.com/parse/classes/_User` in PHP

Comment: The above one is sample URL

Comment: Try changing `"where" => '"name":{"$regex":"$str"}'` to `"where" => '{"name":{"$regex":"$str"}}'`

Comment: can you tell me how I should pass ` --data-urlencode 'where={"name":{"$regex":"^Big Daddy"}}'` in post parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it into the URL:

```
$url = "http://ec2-34-204-170-24.compute-1.amazonaws.com/parse/classes/_User?" . http_build_query($query);
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: can you tell me how I should pass ` --data-urlencode 'where={"name":{"$regex":"^Big Daddy"}}'` in post parameter?

Comment: If you want to get exactly what you have in the CLI you will need `$query = ['where' => '{"name":{"$regex":"^Big Daddy"}}'];`